# jQuery not calling each other

Tags: jquery

Hi I have another issues was just previously solved by member of stackoverflow, really thank you for their prompt reply and professional. The below is JS code where i found that ibox is not calling at all.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ibox = function() {
        // set zoom ratio //
        alert("asdfas");
        resize = 20;
        ////////////////////
        var img = this;
        img.parent().append("<div id='ibox' />");
        var ibox = $("#ibox");
        var elX = 0;
        var elY = 0;

        img.each(function() {
            var el = $(this);

            el.mouseenter(function() {
                ibox.html("");
                var elH = el.height();
                elX = el.position().left - 6; // 6 = CSS#ibox padding+border
                elY = el.position().top - 6;
                var h = el.height();
                var w = el.width();
                var wh;
                checkwh = (h < w) ? (wh = (w / h * resize) / 2) : (wh = (w * resize / h) / 2);

                $(this).clone().prependTo(ibox);
                ibox.css({
                    top: elY + "px",
                    left: elX + "px"
                });

                ibox.stop().fadeTo(200, 1, function() {
                    $(this).animate({top: "-="+(resize/2), left:"-="+wh},400).children("img").animate({height:"+="+resize},400);
                });
            });

            ibox.mouseleave(function() {
                ibox.html("").hide();
            });
        });
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickMe").click(function () { 
    alert("Me");
    }); 

    var html = "";
    var num = 1;

    for (var idx=0; idx<100; idx++)
    {
        if( num == 4) num = 1;
        html += "<img src='image/img" + num + ".jpg' class='grayscale' />";
        num ++;
    }  
    $("#images").html(html);

   $("#images img").ibox();


});
```

do i miss out any calling step here? Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you've not passed the `jQuery` object into the function which encloses your plugin

```
(function($) {
     ....
 }); <-- Oops
```

Change it to this:

```
(function($) {
     ....
 })(jQuery); <-- Yay!
```

There is a good article on plugin authoring which you should read: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: actually, there's no closure involved here.  The plugin makes no reference to externally bound variables, only to the (not) passed parameter.  The plugin is encapsulated within an _immediately invoked (anonymous) function expression_ - he just forgot to invoke it.

Comment: I think you've missed the point, and possibly don't understand why plugins are written this way.  The _sole_ purpose of the IIFE in this case is to allow the use of `$` as a short-hand _alias_ for `jQuery` inside the plugin code.  In other cases, the IIFE can act as an enclosing scope for variables which only the plugin should have access to.  As it happens, the plugin function itself _is_ a closure because it binds on the `$` parameter of the enclosing IIFE.

Comment: @Alnitak - I understand perfectly, having writen a metric crapload of jQuery plugins. What Im not too interested in is explaining the nitty-gritty here - the jQuery documentation on plugin authoring does a better job than I could do. If you feel so inclined, feel free to update this answer as you see fit.

Comment: fine, but as written this is inaccurate and possibly misleading.  By trying to explain too much you've actually weakened your answer.

Comment: @Alnitak - Fair comment. Ive removed the flippancy, and replaced with a link to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped your jQuery plugin inside an *immediately invoked function expression*, except you failed to actually invoke it.

Put  `(jQuery)` after the function expression:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ibox = function() {
        ...
    }
})(jQuery);
```

to turn it from a "void" function expression into one that's actually called.